# Auto CC Outgoing Emails

Tags: email, workflow, account

Our customer service team regularly uses Service Console to communicate with a large number of clients. A handful of those clients ask that we CC all customer service / tech support related communication to a specific email address. Always unique to the customer, it is often something like cs_updates@example.com. As of right now specific "CC to" email address is listed in email templates, in bright red. Users then manually copy this email address into the CC line.

My overall hope is to automate this process based on the account the case belongs to. I will settle for the contact if that is the only way possible. I'm wondering if this can be done in workflows, but I have had little luck finding this type of functionality.

> *Is there a way to specify on an account (even a contact, for that matter) that every time an email is sent, it will auto CC to a specific contact or email address?*

My hope is to eliminate this manual process of copying the address from an email template. This would create a plentiful number of benefits - the foremost being, thoroughness in our email responses.

Comment: Thought of using the **Compliance BCC Email** feature instead?

Comment: @BarneyRubble - this won't work if it's "per Account", compliance is global and I'm sure you don't want to notify customers X and Y that customer Z got a new Case...

Answer (score 1):

I pulled off something like that on normal pages. I don't see why you couldn't achieve the same in Console.

1. Create a field on Account that will hold this email address.
2. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953615/salesforce-create-buttons-and-links-option-custom-url-to-launch-email-template
3. In case of doubts what the hell have you just read - search about "Salesforce URL hacking" or "EmailAuthor.jsp" ;) There's a [Ray Dehler's blog post](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) that's pretty much bible of hacking at Salesforce links, plugging in a template, changing report filter values on the fly...
4. CC field on the email sending form has name "p4" so your custom link should contain `&p4={!Case.Account.CC_Email__c}`. This will be probably too long and Salesforce will complain about too many dots... You can work around that by:

   - making a formula on Case that references it as a shortcut
   - sending a query from [AJAX toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm) that'd retrieve the value.

Comment: "bible of hacking at Salesforce links" -- thanks for the compliment :)